# Selenium webdriver files (Python) seem to be missing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I'm new to python programming so bear with me!

I've recently downloaded Python 3.7.3 along with using pip to successfully install a number of add-on modules (including Numpy, Scipy, Matplotlib, Gamepy, Xlwings and **Selenium**).

With Selenium I'm trying to script a very simple `.py` file to navigate to google and to do a very simple search and then close the tab (code I've recorded, using the `Katalon` plugin, and issues I'm experiencing below!)

### My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class AppDynamicsJob(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # AppDynamics will automatically override this web driver
        # as documented in https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO44/Write+Your+First+Script
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_app_dynamics_job(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        driver.find_element_by_name("q").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Test search")
        driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        driver.close()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        # To know more about the difference between verify and assert,
        # visit https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#validating-results
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

### Errors coming up is

> E
>   ====================================================================== ERROR: test_untitled_test_case (**main**.UntitledTestCase)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\jer_m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 76, in start
>       stdin=PIPE)   File "C:\Users\jer_m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 775, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Users\jer_m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 1178, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/jer_m/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/Test.py", line 12, in setUp
>       self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File "C:\Users\jer_m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 164, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\jer_m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 83, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH.
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 0.009s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)

Much of the I'm python files being referenced are the default files as part of the `Selenium` module so I'm not sure how the paths might have changed (I notice, for example, the `service.py` seems to be specific to the actual driver so it's in the individual browser folder..)

I was contemplating copying the `service.py` file from the Firefox folder, into the "common" folder.

Also, the `subprocess.py` file is throwing up errors and again, as these are library files, I'd have thought they wouldn't cause issues.. Has anybody experienced these and, if so, what have you done t get around this?

The blocks of code within `subprocess.py` are;

```
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                        pass_fds, cwd, env,
                        startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
                        p2cread, p2cwrite,
                        c2pread, c2pwrite,
                        errread, errwrite,
                        restore_signals, start_new_session)
```

and

```
    try:
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                 # no special security
                                 None, None,
                                 int(not close_fds),
                                 creationflags,
                                 env,
                                 os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
                                 startupinfo)
```